# Right limit to zero

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to solve this right limit

$$\lim_{a\to 0+} ab \text{ with }b=\frac{a^2e^{a^{3}}}{e^{a^{3}}-1} $$

But thinking since $a$ goes to zero, it becomes $0b$ = $0$. This answer would of course be too simple so maybe I'm mistaken with what a right limit exactly is. I thought a left or right limit only exists in a system with two equations, eg:

$$-x^2+3 \text{ when } x \leqslant 1$$
$$\frac{1}{2}x+1 \text{ when } x>1 $$

Comment: The denominator of $b$ is zero if $a$ is zero, so you cannot simply "plug in" $a=0$ in the limit. Try writting the limit with the full expression for $b$ in terms of $a$.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong with tinking its a right limit also? Could the $+$ sign in the limit mean something else?

Comment: Yes you are right that this limit is $a$ approaching $0$ from the right. That is what the $+$ means.

Answer (score 1):

HINT
Letting $x=a^3$  the expression becomes
$$\dfrac{e^x}{(e^x-1)/x}$$

Comment: Lol! that looked way above my head but I'm going to give it a try in the morning... super sleepy now you have fun @JeanMarie :)